# Finding Taylor series of $x^{-3}$ about $x=a$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

How to find the Taylor series of $x^{-3}$ about $x = a$?

Usually I can do ones where $f(x) = (x+c)^{-3}$ but when $c=0$, I'm unsure. Even for positive exponents there's a simple way.

Comment: A Taylor series is $$\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(a)(x - a)^n}{n!}$$

Comment: What order polynomial are you looking for?

Comment: Technically the question wanted the first 4 nonzero terms but you can also write the full infinite sum in summation notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x)=x^{-3}$ then $f'(x)=-3x^{-4}$ and $f''(x)=(-3)\times(-4) x^{-5}$ and by induction
$$f^{(n)}(x)=(-1)^n\frac{(n+2)!}{2}x^{-(n+3)}$$
so the Taylor series is

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}(x-a)^n$$

Comment: yeah okay thank you! I was over thinking it and trying to use a power series method.

Comment: You're welcome adel!